# MySQL Query optimization: select all duplicates if none expired, or the newest if one expired

Tags: mysql, optimization, mariadb, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.7

I have this query, it works, I just like to optimize, if possible, here's a fully working [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fe3114196f483f9ff376842a8c69da2b) where you can test it

- Two Items are considered duplicates if they have either the same bundle_id or package_id or service_id
- An item is considered expired and in grace period if `(expires + INTERVAL 5 DAY) >= NOW()`
- An item is not expired if `expires >=NOW()`

I want to do the following

- If duplicates exist, none of them expired, I want to select all of them
- If duplicate exist, some of them expired but others did not, I want to select the items which did not expire
- If duplicates exist, both expired are in the grace period, I'd like to select the most recent.
- I don't want to select items that long expired and are no longer in the grace period
- If an item has no duplicates and is either in the grace period or hasn't expired yet, select it.
- The query should run on MySQL 5.5 and above, the client who needs this query is in the process of upgrading his database and is not done yet.

I select the items in the grace period or haven't expired, `order by expire` date to get the newest I use `LIMIT` to force `group by` to respect the order as per [this issue](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/). Then I use `group by` to filter duplicates. And then I add to that, the items I know has not expired yet

```
          SELECT * FROM (
                    SELECT
                    wtb_orders.orderid,
                    wtb_orders.duration,
                    wtb_orders.is_renew,
                    wtb_orders.bundle_id,
                    wtb_orders.service_id,
                    wtb_orders.object_name,
                    wtb_orders.pkg_id_fk,
                    expires,
                    wtb_tokens.disconnect_time
                    FROM wtb_orders
                    JOIN wtb_tokens ON wtb_orders.orderid=wtb_tokens.orderid
                    WHERE
                        wtb_orders.username= `96190000002` AND
                        (
                            (
                                ((expires + INTERVAL 5 DAY) >= NOW())
                                OR
                                (expires=0 AND wtb_tokens.orderid IS NOT NULL)
                            ) OR
                            expires=0
                        )
                    ORDER by expires DESC LIMIT 1000000
                ) as tmp
                GROUP BY
            tmp.pkg_id_fk,
            tmp.bundle_id,
                tmp.service_id
                    UNION
                (
                    SELECT ord.orderid,ord.duration,ord.is_renew,ord.bundle_id,ord.service_id,ord.object_name,ord.pkg_id_fk,tk.expires,tk.disconnect_time FROM wtb_orders AS ord
                    JOIN wtb_tokens AS tk ON ord.orderid=tk.orderid 
                    WHERE tk.username= ``96190000002``
                    AND (((tk.expires >= NOW())
                    OR (tk.expires=0 AND tk.orderid IS NOT NULL))
                    OR tk.expires=0)
                )
```

I tried optimizing it using [eversql](http://eversql.com) which helps most of the time, It gave me this query, it doesn't run, I get an error on `UNION DISTINCT (SELECT wtb_orders.orderid ...` Which says, `Unrecognized statement near type DISTINCT` and `tmp.pkg_id_fk' in 'group statement` you could check the error [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e50d78aa4083fbaf8d8062f0a8ccd668), please scroll to the bottom

```
 SELECT
        *
    FROM
        (SELECT
            wtb_orders_orderid,
            wtb_orders_duration,
            wtb_orders_is_renew,
            wtb_orders_bundle_id,
            wtb_orders_service_id,
            wtb_orders_object_name,
            wtb_orders_pkg_id_fk,
            wtb_tokens_expires,
            wtb_tokens_disconn_time
        FROM
            ((SELECT
                wtb_orders.orderid AS wtb_orders_orderid,
                wtb_orders.duration AS wtb_orders_duration,
                wtb_orders.is_renew AS wtb_orders_is_renew,
                wtb_orders.bundle_id AS wtb_orders_bundle_id,
                wtb_orders.service_id AS wtb_orders_service_id,
                wtb_orders.object_name AS wtb_orders_object_name,
                wtb_orders.pkg_id_fk AS wtb_orders_pkg_id_fk,
                wtb_tokens.expires AS wtb_tokens_expires,
                wtb_tokens.disconnect_time AS wtb_tokens_disconn_time
            FROM
                wtb_orders
            JOIN
                wtb_tokens
                    ON wtb_orders.orderid = wtb_tokens.orderid
            WHERE
                wtb_orders.username = '96190000002'
                AND (
                    wtb_tokens.expires = 0
                )
            ORDER BY
                wtb_tokens.expires DESC LIMIT 1000000)
        UNION
        DISTINCT (SELECT
            wtb_orders.orderid AS wtb_orders_orderid,
            wtb_orders.duration AS wtb_orders_duration,
            wtb_orders.is_renew AS wtb_orders_is_renew,
            wtb_orders.bundle_id AS wtb_orders_bundle_id,
            wtb_orders.service_id AS wtb_orders_service_id,
            wtb_orders.object_name AS wtb_orders_object_name,
            wtb_orders.pkg_id_fk AS wtb_orders_pkg_id_fk,
            wtb_tokens.expires AS wtb_tokens_expires,
            wtb_tokens.disconnect_time AS wtb_tokens_disconn_time
        FROM
            wtb_orders
        JOIN
            wtb_tokens
                ON wtb_orders.orderid = wtb_tokens.orderid
        WHERE
            wtb_orders.username = '96190000002'
            AND (((wtb_tokens.expires = 0
            AND wtb_tokens.orderid IS NOT NULL)))
        ORDER BY
            wtb_tokens.expires DESC LIMIT 1000000)
    UNION
    DISTINCT (SELECT
        wtb_orders.orderid AS wtb_orders_orderid,
        wtb_orders.duration AS wtb_orders_duration,
        wtb_orders.is_renew AS wtb_orders_is_renew,
        wtb_orders.bundle_id AS wtb_orders_bundle_id,
        wtb_orders.service_id AS wtb_orders_service_id,
        wtb_orders.object_name AS wtb_orders_object_name,
        wtb_orders.pkg_id_fk AS wtb_orders_pkg_id_fk,
        wtb_tokens.expires AS wtb_tokens_expires,
        wtb_tokens.disconnect_time AS wtb_tokens_disconn_time
    FROM
        wtb_orders
    JOIN
        wtb_tokens
            ON wtb_orders.orderid = wtb_tokens.orderid
    WHERE
        wtb_orders.username = '96190000002'
        AND ((((wtb_tokens.expires + INTERVAL 5 DAY) >= NOW())))
    ORDER BY
        wtb_tokens.expires DESC LIMIT 1000000)
) AS union1
ORDER BY
union1.wtb_tokens_expires DESC LIMIT 1000000) AS tmp
GROUP BY
tmp.pkg_id_fk,
tmp.bundle_id,
tmp.service_id
UNION
(
SELECT
    ord.orderid,
    ord.duration,
    ord.is_renew,
    ord.bundle_id,
    ord.service_id,
    ord.object_name,
    ord.pkg_id_fk,
    tk.expires,
    tk.disconnect_time
FROM
    wtb_orders AS ord
JOIN
    wtb_tokens AS tk
        ON ord.orderid = tk.orderid
WHERE
    tk.username = '96190000002'
    AND (
        tk.expires = 0
    )
)
UNION
DISTINCT (SELECT
ord.orderid,
ord.duration,
ord.is_renew,
ord.bundle_id,
ord.service_id,
ord.object_name,
ord.pkg_id_fk,
tk.expires,
tk.disconnect_time
FROM
wtb_orders AS ord
JOIN
wtb_tokens AS tk
ON ord.orderid = tk.orderid
WHERE
tk.username = '96190000002'
AND (((tk.expires = 0
AND tk.orderid IS NOT NULL))))
UNION
DISTINCT (SELECT
ord.orderid,
ord.duration,
ord.is_renew,
ord.bundle_id,
ord.service_id,
ord.object_name,
ord.pkg_id_fk,
tk.expires,
tk.disconnect_time
FROM
wtb_orders AS ord
JOIN
wtb_tokens AS tk
ON ord.orderid = tk.orderid
WHERE
tk.username = '96190000002'
AND (((tk.expires >= NOW()))))
```

Even If I manage to fix the eversql query, I'm not convinced it's better than mine, okay it removes the OR and uses union, but I had to use  `LIMIT` to force group by to respect the order, not because it's a good thing. And I'm sure this is a bad practice but I needed a solution.

The optimized query uses 2 limits, so it creates 2 temporary tables for nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For performance, don't try to do it all in one statement.

Avoid non-sargable expressions, such as `(expires + INTERVAL 5 DAY) >= NOW()`; instead say `(expires >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY)`

Probably it would be better to do 3 queries to test for the 3 possible dups (`bundle_id`, etc).

If it would be OK to pick the newest expired `bundle_id` dup without seeing if the other two have newer dups, then do so.  That is 3 *separate* queries, and stop when one is found.  If all 3 fail to find a dup, then fall into the 4th query -- find all dups.

If that is not OK, the *probably* a `UNION` of those 3 dups would be optimal:

```
SELECT
    FROM (
        ( SELECT id FROM ... ) -- find latest bundle_id dup, if any
        UNION DISTINCT
        ( SELECT id FROM ... ) -- find latest ... dup, if any
        UNION DISTINCT
        ( SELECT id FROM ... ) -- find latest ... dup, if any
         ) AS x
    JOIN ... to get other columns
    ORDER BY ...  LIMIT 1  -- Get the latest of the 3 or fewer
```

Since I am talking about multiple queries, you would need to either use a Stored Procedure so you can have IF statements or use client code to orchestrate the queries.

```
IF the above query returned no rows
THEN
    SELECT ... -- all dups
END IF
```

Once you have restructured the queries this way, I'll help you with optimal indexes.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see the datatypes, indexes, etc.

(I left out issues about the grace period; perhaps that won't double the number of queries.)

5.5 is probably not too old to get this optimized.